# How to stay on the same page after Html.BeginForm without refresh or reload

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**The Objective:**

I would like to know, how to stay on the same page without loading again the content after submit the form using" *@using Html.Beginform...*

**The Code:**

Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(DetailHvmModel model)
    {
        HvmService.Save(model);
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(Actions.Valoration_Save, Controllers.Valoration, FormMethod.Post))
       { 
//Html
       }
```

Comment: do you mean "how to stay on the same page"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Ajax instead, you can do this easily with the helper Ajax.BeginForm, see here for more

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform(v=vs.108).aspx

Also this compares the way you have it with the Ajax approach

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429164/Html-BeginForm-vs-Ajax-BeginForm-in-MVC3

Comment: Okey!! I'm gonna take a look, Ty!